# Does $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1 + nx^2}$ converge uniformly for $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Does $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1 + nx^2}$ converge uniformly to $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n = f(x) = 0$

For $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly, I have to show that $sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \rightarrow 0$

$sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |\frac{x}{1 + nx^2}| = \frac{1}{1 + n}$???

So I was thinking, $x = 1$ will give me the largest value, so $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1 + n} = 0$, so that would mean $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly, right? However, the answer says that $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly to $f(x)$. Why is this?

Comment: I think that ${f_n}\left( x \right) = \frac{x}{{1 + n{x^2}}}$ attains the maximum value at $x=1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: $$\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| {{f_n}\left( x \right) - 0} \right| = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| {\frac{x}
{{1 + n{x^2}}}} \right| = {\left( {\left| {\frac{x}
{{1 + n{x^2}}}} \right|} \right)_{x = 1/\sqrt n }} = \frac{1}
{{2\sqrt n }} \to 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| {{f_n}\left( x \right) - 0} \right| = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \left| {\frac{x}{{1 + n{x^2}}}} \right| = {\left( {\left| {\frac{x}{{1 + n{x^2}}}} \right|} \right)_{x = 1/\sqrt n }} = \frac{1}
{{2\sqrt n }} \to 0.$$
So, $f_n(x)$ converge uniformly to $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim} \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim} \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |\frac{x}{1+nx^2} - 0| = \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim} |\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}| = 0$, therefore $f_n$ does converge uniformly.

Comment: $${f_n}\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt n }}} \right) = \frac{1}{{2\sqrt n }} > \frac{1}{{n + 1}}$$?

Comment: do you really mean $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1+n}=1$???

Comment: You got your computations wrong mate. $f_n$ achieves its maximum at $x=1/\sqrt{n}$

Comment: True, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @GabrielRomon Replace $x$ with ($z$ and then with) $n$ changes things right? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267659/check-if-frac1z2-frac-1-n-n-1-infty-is-uniform-or-at-least-po