# Complex non-/uniform convergence: About dependence of the index $N$ on modulus $|z|$ vs complex number $z$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, epsilon-delta

**Assumptions**: Let $A \subseteq \mathbb C$. Let $f_n,f: A \to \mathbb C$, for all $n \ge 1$. As to whether or not $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges uniformly or pointwise to $f$ (on $A$):

---

**Definitions:**

Complex pointwise convergence is true:

> For any $(\varepsilon,z) \in (0,\infty) \times A$, there exists $N_{(\varepsilon,z)} > 0$ s.t. $|f_n(z)-f(z)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $n > N_{(\varepsilon,z)}$.

Complex uniform  convergence is true:

> For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N_{\varepsilon} > 0$ s.t. $|f_n(z)-f(z)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $n > N_{\varepsilon}$ and $z \in A$.

Complex uniform convergence is false:

> There exists $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. for all $N > 0$, there exists $n_{\varepsilon,N} > N$ and $z_{\varepsilon,N} \in A$ s.t. $|f_n(z)-f(z)| \ge \varepsilon$.

---

**Questions**:

---

1. What I understand about these definitions in particular for the $|z|$:

For (real uniform continuity and) real uniform convergence, what we want is our ($\delta$ and) $N$ to not depend on $x$.

For complex uniform convergence (and I guess complex uniform continuity), well...what we want in disproving uniform convergence seems to be showing that our $N$ (and I guess $\delta$) depends on $|z|$, eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267659/check-if-frac1z2-frac-1-n-n-1-infty-is-uniform-or-at-least-po) (for $\{\frac{1}{z^2+\frac 1 n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$), but technically $N$ doesn't depend on $z$ given its dependence on $|z|$.

**Do I understand this correctly?**

- 1.1. **I mean, are there examples** where disproving uniform convergence really shows dependence on really $z$ (and not just $|z|$)? I have a feeling it's really gonna be just $|z|$ because $|z|$ is what we get when we do $|f_n(z)-f(z)|$.

---

2. Does $N$'s dependence, eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267659/check-if-frac1z2-frac-1-n-n-1-infty-is-uniform-or-at-least-po) (for $\{\frac{1}{z^2+\frac 1 n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$), on $|z|$ even though we (might) have independence of $z$ given $|z|$ mean that $N$ **still 'depends' on $z$** anyway?

I guess yes because well...$|z|$ isn't (necessarily) fixed so for different moduli, we have different (choices for) $z$.

Comment: I see the germ of a good problem here, but the resolution is to better understand the definition.  Which direction do you want to go?  Picking $N$ that gives uniform bound $|f(z) - f_k(z)| \lt \epsilon$ for all $k \ge N$ and all $z\in A$ is independent of $z$ *and* also independent of $|z|$.  If your choice of $N$ depends "only" on $|z|$, that's kind of special but you could not claim $N$ is independent of $z$ could you?

Comment: @hardmath not really sure what you mean but thanks for commenting. what i'm asking is like...(perhaps i was not so clear) (1) - technically $N$ doesn't depend on $z$ given $|z|$? --> so your answer is yes/no? (1.1) i mean do you know of any examples that's really $z$ and not just $|z|$? (2)  - well independence from $z$ given $|z|$ doesn't necessarily mean independence from $z$ unconditionally...right? i think there's an analogous probability thing. but basically the dependence on $|z|$ IS the dependence on $z$? --> so your answer is yes?

Comment: If you have a scheme for picking $N$ that depends "only" on $|z|$, you have **not** thus found a way to choose $N$ that works for all $z$ simultaneously.

Comment: @hardmath ok i assume your answer to (2) is yes and (1.1) is there isn't any. As for (1), but technically $N$ is independent of $z$ GIVEN $|z|$ ?

Comment: The definition of uniform convergence requires us to show there exists $N$ that works for all $z \in A$.  If you have $N$ that works for some but not all $z\in A$, e.g. for those where $|z|$ is fixed or otherwise restricted, that falls short of proving uniform convergence.  You would instead have uniform convergence on the appropriate subset of $A$, such as on a circle of radius $R$ around the complex origin (points where $|z|=R$).  This notion might be useful in your application, but you would be misleading Readers if you said $N$ doesn't depend on $z$.

Comment: @hardmath a weird thought: there's this thing in probability where $X$ and $Y$ are independent only if but not if $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent right? so what's the idea here: dependent on $z$ if and only if dependent on $|z|$? or just if? or just only if?

Comment: @hardmath please help here [Uniform convergence: Question about in/dependence of the indices on other variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267741/uniform-convergence-question-about-in-dependence-of-the-indices-on-other-variab)