# Check if $\{\frac{1}{z^2+\frac 1 n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is uniform convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

> Check if $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is uniform (or at least pointwise) convergent, where $$f_n(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+\frac 1 n}, f_n: A \to \mathbb C,$$ $$A = \{z \in \mathbb C | |z| < 1, Re(z)>0\}$$ $$\stackrel{\text{I believe}}{=} \{z \in \mathbb C | |z|^2 < 1, Re(z)>0\}$$ $$\stackrel{aka}{=} \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | x^2+y^2<1, x>0\}$$ i.e. (I believe) the open right half of the unit disc.

- Note: $\frac{n}{nz^2+1} = \frac{1}{z^2+\frac 1 n}$, and I guess $\frac{n}{nz^2+1}$ is very different from $\frac{z}{nz^2+1}$ or $\frac{x}{nx^2+1}$ as in here: [Does $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1 + nx^2}$ converge uniformly for $x \in \mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157218/does-f-nx-fracx1-nx2-converge-uniformly-for-x-in-mathbbr)

---

1. Is this correct for **Pointwise**? --> See here: [Check if $\{\frac{1}{z^2+\frac 1 n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is uniform (or at least pointwise) convergent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267659/check-if-frac1z2-frac-1-n-n-1-infty-is-uniform-or-at-least-po)

- Related question: [Complex non-/uniform convergence: About dependence of the index $N$ on modulus $|z|$ vs complex number $z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267761/complex-non-uniform-convergence-about-dependence-of-the-index-n-on-modulus)

---

2. Is this correct for **Uniform**? (Again, I'll type details as an answer.)

- Related question: [Uniform convergence: Question about in/dependence of the indices on other variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4267741/uniform-convergence-question-about-in-dependence-of-the-indices-on-other-variab)

---

3. **Quick clarification**: Just because the $N$ in proving pointwise convergence is true technically has a '$z$' in its formula, **doesn't mean not** uniformly convergent right?

**I guess yes because** in general for a uniformly convergent sequence it's possible we could still find an $N$ that depends on $z$ but another $N$ that doesn't depend on $z$, i.e. we didn't look hard enough or something. After all, the condition for uniform convergence is that we find some large enough index $N$ not that every damn index $N$ is gonna be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler to just try say $z_n=1/n\in A$ (for e.g. $n>2)$, since things are going real bad near zero.
$$f(1/n)-f_n(1/n)=\frac1{1/n^2}-\frac1{1/n^2+1/n}=n^2-\frac{n^2}{1+n}>n^2-\frac {n^2}{0+n}=n(n-1)> n. $$
Hence $\sup_{z\in A}|f(z)-f_n(z)|>n$.

Comment: ok thanks. is my answer correct please? or if it's too long does it look correct please?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean when you write $$ a <b \overset{\text {actually}} = c$$ because $b\neq c$. You refer to  (2.1) but later make a bullet point that starts with 2.1 (not (2.1)). It looks like the broad strokes might be right on a glance. Similar issues with other post

Comment: thanks Calvin Khor. why are $b$ and $c$ not equal? $\frac{1}{\varepsilon = \frac12} - 1 = 1$ right?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon well OK, *now* I understand; didn't realise $\epsilon$ was fixed. But I have no ability to understand things like $a(=)b$ or $1/(a=b)-c=d$, if you don't explain further.  IMO, it would have been better to just write $$\dots =\frac1{N+1} = \frac{\frac1\epsilon-1}{N+1},$$ or if you really want the brackets,
 $$\dots=\frac1{N+1} \left(= \frac{\frac1\epsilon-1}{N+1}\right),$$ so that I can still understand after deleting everything in the brackets. Or maybe even write out a full sentence, like: "
  $$...=\frac1{N+1},$$
which is actually equal to $\frac{\frac1\epsilon-1}{N+1}$."

Comment: ok thanks Calvin Khor. going to your answer, 1 - your choices for $\varepsilon$ and $n_{\varepsilon,N}$ what exactly? for $n_{\varepsilon,N}$, i guess your choice is the same as mine $n_{\varepsilon,N}=N+1$?

Comment: 2 - how would you do this if we didn't conveniently have that $A$ intersects $\mathbb R$? Pick a point that has modulus of $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon (1) for my answer, I have no interest in choosing $\epsilon$ or really any quantities directly found in the definition you wrote, which would make writing the answer a hassle. It simply suffices to find $z_n$ such that $|f_n(z_n) - f(z_n)|$ does not converge to zero. (2) yes, choose a sequence such that $z_n \to 0$, since $0$ is the problem point of the limit function (and not of any of the $f_n$s). My experience is that it doesn't matter what the $f_n$ are, this usually works

Comment: ok thanks Calvin Khor (btw Daily comment vote limit reached)

Answer (score 0):

outline for uniform:

I think no, $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not uniformly convergent (to its pointwise convergent limit).

Proof: Choose $\varepsilon = \frac12$. Let $N>0$. We must find $n_{\varepsilon,N} > N$ and $z_{\varepsilon,N} \in A$ s.t.  $|f_n(z)-f(z)| \ge \varepsilon = \frac12$. Choose $n_{\varepsilon,N} = N+1$ and any $z_{\varepsilon,N}$ s.t. $|z_{\varepsilon,N}|^2 < \frac{1}{N+1} (\stackrel{\text{actually}}{=}) 
\frac{\frac 1 \varepsilon - 1}{N+1} $ (see (2.1)). QED

- 2.1. Such $z_{\varepsilon,N}$ exists because: For $0 < \frac{1}{N+1} < 1$ (where $\frac{1}{N+1} < 1$ because $N>0$), we can think of $\frac{1}{N+1}$ as a (positive) squared radius smaller than 1: Then pick an even smaller squared radius $0 < r < \frac{1}{N+1} (< 1)$. Then pick any $z_{\varepsilon,N} \in A$ whose radius squared is $|z_{\varepsilon,N}|^2 = r$.

---

details for uniform:

$$|\frac{1}{z^2+\frac 1 n} -\frac 1 {z^2}| $$
$$=|\frac{-\frac{1}{n}}{(z^2+\frac 1 n)(z^2)}| $$
$$=|\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{(z^2+\frac 1 n)(z^2)}| $$
$$=|\frac{1}{n(z^2+\frac 1 n)(z^2)}| $$
$$=|\frac{1}{(nz^2+1)(z^2)}| $$
$$=|\frac{1}{nz^2+1}| |\frac{1}{z^2}| $$
$$= |\frac{1}{z^2}| |\frac{1}{nz^2+1}|$$
$$= \frac{1}{|z|^2} \frac{1}{|nz^2+1|}$$
$$ \ge \frac{1}{|nz^2+1|} \ \text{because} \ z \in A$$
$$ \ge \frac{1}{n|z|^2+1} \ \text{by triangle inequality}$$
$$= \frac{1}{(N+1)|z|^2+1} \ \text{by choice of n}$$
$$>  \frac 12 \ \text{by choice of z because...}$$

$$\frac{1}{(N+1)|z|^2+1} >  \frac 12$$

$$\iff 2 > (N+1)|z|^2+1$$

$$\iff 1> (N+1)|z|^2$$

$$\iff \frac{1}{N+1} > |z|^2$$